# Block inline scripts from executing?

Tags: javascript, browsers, testing, script

I need to test a page with no scripts running/executing. I've tried NoScript and uBlock but they seem to only stop externally linked scripts from being executed, not those in ... tags.

Any suggestions how I can achieve this from the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Just turn of JavaScript in your browser.

[Disable JavaScript in Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BYOQskiuGU0):

> - Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu  in the top right hand corner of your browser
> - Select Settings
> - Click Show advanced settings
> - Under the "Privacy" section, click the Content settings button.
> - In the "Javascript" section, select "Do not allow any site to run JavaScript" or "Allow all sites to run JavaScript (recommended)"

[Disable JavaScript in Firefox](https://techjourney.net/disable-javascript-in-firefox/):

> - In Firefox's address bar, type about:config and press Enter.
> - Click I'll be careful, I promise! button.
> - In the search bar, search for javascript.enabled.
> - Double click on the row of preference named javascript.enabled to change the value to False. ...
> - JavaScript is now disabled.

[Disable JavaScript in Internet Explorer](http://www.technipages.com/internet-explorer-enabledisable-javascript):

> - Select the Gear in the upper-right corner of the screen or the “Tools” menu if you have the menu bar enabled, then select “Internet
>     Options“.
> - Select the “Security” tab.
> - Select the zone you wish to modify. In most cases, it will be “Internet“.
> - Select the “Custom level…” button.
> - Scroll down to the “Scripting” area and select the radio button to “Enable” or “Disable” it “Active scripting“. You may also opt for IE11
>     to “Prompt” you to allow scripts to run.
> - Select “OK“, then “OK” again.

[Disable JavaScript in Edge](https://kb.iu.edu/d/bcyv):

> - Launch the Edit Group Policy program.
> - Expand the User Configuration folder.
> - Expand the Administrative Templates folder.
> - Expand the Windows Components folder.
> - Expand the Microsoft Edge folder.
> - Double-click Allows you to run scripts, like Javascript.
> - Choose Disabled, and click Ok to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox add-on [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/noscript/) should be able to block *all* JavaScript, including the JS included in the current page.

Just make sure that you don’t enable the setting that the current page is always allowed to run JS (it’s the first setting in the first tab).